# jQuery Knob max values

Tags: jquery, jquery-knob

I have the following JS code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.dial').each(function () {

    var elm = $(this);
    var color = elm.attr("data-fgColor");
    var perc = elm.attr("value");

    elm.knob({
        'value': 0,
        'min':0,
        'max':200, // Set to 200 as a max
        "skin":"tron",
        "readOnly":true,
        "thickness":.2,
        'dynamicDraw': true,
        "displayInput":false,
        "font": 'Lato'
    });

    $({value: 0}).animate({ value: perc }, {
        duration: 120,
        easing: 'swing',
        progress: function () {
            elm.val(Math.ceil(this.value)).trigger('change')
        }
    });

    //circular progress bar color
    $(this).append(function() {
        elm.parent().parent().find('.circular-bar-content').css('color',color);
        elm.parent().parent().find('.circular-bar-content label').text(perc+' points');
        elm.parent().parent().find('.circular-bar-content span').text(perc+' proposals');
        elm.parent().parent().find('.circular-bar-content .jobs').text(perc+' proposals');
        elm.parent().parent().find('.circular-bar-content .conv').text(perc+'%'); // THIS ROW
    });

   });

  });
```

But the one with a comment on // THIS ROW i don't want it to be limited to 200 as I'm pulling data from a database this line I want to specify a different value how can this be done?

Which outputs this html once the PHP from the database has been rendered

```
 <div class="col-md-3">
                  <div class="circular-bar">
                      <input type="text" class="dial" data-angleOffset=-125 data-angleArc=250 data-fgColor="#D2207E" data-width="150" data-height="150" data-linecap=round value="50.00">
                      <div class="circular-bar-content">
                          <strong style="padding-left: 8px; padding-top: -20px;">Conv Rate</strong>
                          <p class="conv"></p>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
```

Comment: anyone know how to do this?

Comment: no one know how to do this at all?